# Aurelia - Hide/Show Div based on function result

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Using Aurelia, I am looking for similar behavior to Angular 1 where I can use a function with `ng-show`. Such as:

```
<div ng-show='isShown()'></div>
```

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

**app.js**

```
export class App {
    this.options = ['opt1', 'opt2', 'opt3', 'opt4, 'opt5'];
    this.current = "";
    isShown() {
        return (this.current === 'opt1');
    }
}
```

**app.html**

```
<select value.bind="current">
    <option repeat.for="opt of options" model.bind="opt">${opt}</option>
</select>

<div if.bind="isShown()">...</div>
```

If the initial value is `opt1`, the div is shown, but it doesn't show/hide when the select changes. The only way I can get this to work is by doing this:

```
<div if.bind="current === 'opt1'"></div>
```

This isn't bad in this situation but I was hoping to do something like this which I feel would work better with a function in JS rather than in the markup:

```
<div if.bind="current === 'opt1' || current === 'opt2' || current === 'opt3'"></div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to make your function a getter:

```
get isShown() {
    return (this.current === 'opt1');
}
```

and:

```
<div if.bind="isShown">Show/Hide</div>
```

but this way it will be dirty checked, to avoid that you can use computedFrom:

```
import { computedFrom } from 'aurelia-framework';

export class App {

    constructor() {
        this.options = ['opt1', 'opt2', 'opt3', 'opt4', 'opt5'];
        this.current = '';
    }

    @computedFrom('current')
    get isShown() {
        return (this.current === 'opt1');
    }

}
```

You can also use the `@observable`:

```
import { observable } from 'aurelia-framework';

export class App {

    isShown = false;
    @observable current = '';

    currentChanged(newValue, oldValue) {
        this.isShown = (newValue === 'opt1');
    }

}
```

And you can also use BindingEngine:

```
import { BindingEngine, inject } from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(BindingEngine)
export class App {

    isShown = false;
    current = '';
    options = ['opt1', 'opt2', 'opt3', 'opt4', 'opt5'];

    constructor(bindingEngine) {
        this.bindingEngine = bindingEngine;

        this.bindingEngine
            .propertyObserver(this, 'current')
            .subscribe(this.currentChanged.bind(this));
    }

    currentChanged(newValue, oldValue) {
        this.isShown = (newValue === 'opt1');
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added the @observable approach

Comment: Worked great! If you are using ES2015 there are some slight changes to be made which can found here: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-computed-properties/1